# Order a model with conditions in Rails (3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

Lets say there is a model called Event. I want to display important and current events first, so i have the attributes important (boolean) and enddate (date).

Now I want to get all events where `important == true` and where `enddate >= today` first, all others should be ordered by `created_at`.

I want to avoid doing `events = important_events + not_important_events` as this would return an array insted of an activerecord. Does anyone knows an elegant way to order a model in rails?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will return newest record first and fulfil your conditions.

```
important == true
enddate >= today

@events1 = Event.where(:important => true).where('enddate >= ?', Date.today).order(:created_at => :desc)
@events2 = Event.where(:important => false).where('enddate <= ?', Date.today).order(:created_at => :desc)
@events = @events1.or(@events2)
```

"OR" works only in ActiveRecod(5+).

Comment: Thanks, but this will only show important events. I would like to see also non important events, but important and current events first.

Comment: I updated my answer or you can use in a single Query like @Sajin's answer

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm still working with rails 3... And when I do '@events1 + @events2' I will get an array insted of an activerecord.

Answer (score 0):

Try (for ActiveRecord 5+):

```
@events = Event.where(:important => true, 'enddate >= ?', Date.today).or(Event.where.not(:important => true, 'enddate >= ?', Date.today).order(:created_at => :desc))
```